# HackerRank Angular Basic Test Weather App

Tags: javascript, angular

I am taking the [HackerRank Angular Basic Skills Test](https://www.hackerrank.com/skills-verification/angular_basic) and trying to make a [weather app](https://hrcdn.net/s3_pub/istreet-assets/aiYyB8bIMufQ00lpPduPbQ/weather-component.gif)

I have a `weatherDetails.component` with the following code

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

    @Component({
      selector: "weather-details",
      templateUrl: "./weatherDetails.component.html",
      styleUrls: ["./weatherDetails.component.scss"],
    })
    export class WeatherDetails implements OnInit {
      @Input() weatherData: data[];
    
      city: string = "";
    
      ngOnInit() {}
    }
    
    interface data {
      name: string;
      temperature: string;
      wind: string;
      humidity: string;
    }
```

The child component inherits `weatherData` from its parent

```
weatherData = [
    {
      name: "San Jose",
      temperature: "36º F",
      wind: "31Kmph",
      humidity: "66%",
    },
    {
      name: "Seattle",
      temperature: "30º F",
      wind: "4Kmph",
      humidity: "9%",
    },
    {
      name: "New York",
      temperature: "20º F",
      wind: "8Kmph",
      humidity: "61%",
    },
    {
      name: "Chicago",
      temperature: "27º F",
      wind: "35Kmph",
      humidity: "2%",
    },
    {
      name: "Atlanta",
      temperature: "22º F",
      wind: "25Kmph",
      humidity: "5%",
    },
    {
      name: "Austin",
      temperature: "25º F",
      wind: "1Kmph",
      humidity: "5%",
    },
    {
      name: "Denver",
      temperature: "30º F",
      wind: "8Kmph",
      humidity: "48%",
    },
  ];
```

I am rendering the child component via `weatherDetails.component.html` with classes removed for better readability

```
<div>

  <section>
    <label>Enter City: </label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="city" type="text" placeholder="Seattle" data-test-id="app-input"/>
  </section>

  <section *ngFor="let weather of weatherData">
    <div *ngIf="city.toUpperCase() === weather.name.toUpperCase()">
        <div *ngIf="city" data-test-id="weather-details">
            <div>
              <button>
                <i>wb_sunny</i>
              </button>
              <span data-test-id="output-temperature">{{weather.temperature}}</span>
            </div>
            <div>
              <div data-test-id="output-wind">
                Wind: {{weather.wind}}
              </div>
              <div data-test-id="output-humidity">
                Humidity: {{weather.humidity}}
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="city.toUpperCase() !== weather.name.toUpperCase()" data-test-id="no-results">No Results Found</div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

My approach was to use two-way binding via `[(ngModel)]="city"` in `input` and store the `city` variable in my component.

As I  loop through the array of objects in `weatherData` via

```
*ngFor="let weather of weatherData"
```

every time the `input` value is changed, I would use

```
*ngIf="city.toUpperCase() === weather.name.toUpperCase()"
```

to check if the `input` value matches the `weather of weatherData` object and render the `div` if it does.

My problem is that the `div` that outputs "No Results Found" when the `input` value does not match any object in `weather of weatherData` is a child of the `div` that renders the app. So I can't render "No Results Found" because its

```
*ngIf="city.toUpperCase() !== weather.name.toUpperCase()"
```

logic clashes with its parent.

How do I rewrite my code so that I can render "No Results Found" when the `input` value does not match any object in `weather of weatherData`?

My weather app with input of 'S' (should render "No Results Found" but is blank) [image: weather app]

My weather app with input of 'Seattle" [image: weather app]

Comment: Not the right way to solve this problem. NgFor loop for searching is bad. Take all this stuff to your component.ts file and create a helper function which will be called at ngmodelchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work.
Here I have moved the logic to the component file instead of the HTML file to check if the city exists or not. Also, a button to validate the value on click of it.
so I took a function "validatedata()" to validate the city entered and to return the result.
mainly to display the invalid city. Take a variable "invaliddata" of type boolean to display HTML based on its true or false value.
*Weatherdetails.component.html*

```
   <section>
  <label>Enter City: </label>
  <input [(ngModel)]="city" type="text" placeholder="Seattle" id="app-input" />
</section>
<button (click)="validatedata()">Get Weather</button>

<section >
  <div *ngIf ="!invaliddata">
    <h2>The current weather in {{this.enteredData.name}} is </h2>
    <div id="output-temperature">
      Temperature : {{this.enteredData.temperature}}
    </div>
    <div id="output-wind">
      Wind: {{this.enteredData.wind}}
    </div>
    <div id="output-humidity">
      Humidity: {{this.enteredData.humidity}}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf ="invaliddata">
    <h3>Please Enter valid city</h3>
  </div>
</section>



*WeatherdetailsComponent.ts*

    import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { resetFakeAsyncZone } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { WeatherdataService } from './../weatherdata.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-weatherdetails',
  templateUrl: './weatherdetails.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./weatherdetails.component.css'],
  providers: [WeatherdataService]

})
export class WeatherdetailsComponent {
  getdata: any[];
  city: string = "";
  enteredData: any[];
  invaliddata: boolean;
  constructor(public weatherData: WeatherdataService) { }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getdata = this.weatherData.getdata();


  }
  public validatedata() {
    if (this.city) {
      for (var i = 0; i <= this.getdata.length; i++) {
        if (((this.getdata[i].name).toUpperCase()) == ((this.city).toUpperCase())) {
          this.enteredData = this.getdata[i];
          console.log(this.enteredData);
          this.invaliddata = false;
          break;
        }
        else {
          this.invaliddata = true;
        }
      }
    }
    else {
      alert("Please enter a City Name");

    }
  }
}

interface data {
  name: string;
  temperature: string;
  wind: string;
  humidity: string;
}


*weatherdata.Service.ts*
 
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WeatherdataService {

  getdata(){
    return[
        {
            name: "San Jose",
            temperature: "36º F",
            wind: "31Kmph",
            humidity: "66%",
          },
          {
            name: "Seattle",
            temperature: "30º F",
            wind: "4Kmph",
            humidity: "9%",
          },
          {
            name: "New York",
            temperature: "20º F",
            wind: "8Kmph",
            humidity: "61%",
          },
          {
            name: "Chicago",
            temperature: "27º F",
            wind: "35Kmph",
            humidity: "2%",
          },
          {
            name: "Atlanta",
            temperature: "22º F",
            wind: "25Kmph",
            humidity: "5%",
          },
          {
            name: "Austin",
            temperature: "25º F",
            wind: "1Kmph",
            humidity: "5%",
          },
          {
            name: "Denver",
            temperature: "30º F",
            wind: "8Kmph",
            humidity: "48%",
          },
    ]
}}
```

The result is as shown below.
[image]

valid output result looks as below:
[image]

Note: Kindly note that I have not worked on CSS part

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Hackerrank Angular Intermediate certification refer to this link
https://youtu.be/jJxfsZw7jcE